# Checkbox de array no guarda todos los valores seleccionados

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

Estimados he creado un formulario donde tengo unas opciones de checkbox, donde obtengo los valores en el estado pero al enviar solo me guarda el valor de primer elemento o checkbox por mas que esten marcados 3 solo guarda el valor del primero, voy a dejar el codigo y captura del problema solo nesecito resolver la seleccion de los checkbox de los valores que se seleccionan, en este caso solo guarda el valor del pirmer check,

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { preRegisterAddNew } from "../../redux/actions/PreRegister";
import { useForm } from "../../hooks/useForm";

const rubrosData = [
  { name: "Rubro 1" },
  { name: "Rubro 2" },
  { name: "Rubro 3" },
  { name: "Rubro 4" },
  { name: "Rubro 5" },
];

let paises = [
  { value: "", label: "[Seleccione Pais]" },
  { value: "1", label: "Perú" },
  { value: "2", label: "Chile" },
  { value: "3", label: "Argentina" },
  { value: "4", label: "Brasil" },
  { value: "5", label: "México" },
];

let empresas = [
  { value: "", label: "[Seleccione Empresa]" },
  { value: "1", label: "Empresa 1" },
  { value: "2", label: "Empresa 2" },
  { value: "3", label: "Empresa 3" },
  { value: "4", label: "Empresa 4" },
  { value: "5", label: "Empresa 5" },
];

let compradores = [
  { value: "", label: "[Seleccione Comprador]" },
  { value: "1", label: "Comprador 1" },
  { value: "2", label: "Comprador 2" },
  { value: "3", label: "Comprador 3" },
  { value: "4", label: "Comprador 4" },
  { value: "5", label: "Comprador 5" },
];

export const FormPreRegistro = ({ handleValidated }) => {

  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(false);
  const [chkRubros, setchkRubros] = useState([]);

  

  const [formValues, handleInputChange] = useForm({
    idFiscal: "",
    pais: "",
    empresa: "",
    comprador: "",
    comentario: "",
  });

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  
  const [ rubro ] = chkRubros;
  const { idFiscal, pais, empresa, comprador, comentario } = formValues;

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(
      preRegisterAddNew(idFiscal, pais, empresa, comprador, comentario, rubro )
    );
    handleValidated();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setchkRubros(rubrosData);
  }, []);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, checked } = e.target;

    let tempRubro = chkRubros.map((rubro) =>
      rubro.name === name ? { ...rubro, isChecked: checked } : rubro
    );
    setchkRubros(tempRubro);
  };

  return (
    <form name="form" className="form-group" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div className="row">
        <div className="form-group col-12 mb-3">
          <label htmlFor="idFiscal">N° Id. Fiscal</label>
          <input
            className="form-control"
            type="text"
            name="idFiscal"
            autoComplete="off"
            value={idFiscal}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group col-12 mb-3">
          <label htmlFor="pais">País</label>
          <select
            className="form-select"
            name="pais"
            value={pais}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
          >
            {paises.map((item) => {
              return (
                <option name="pais" key={item.value} value={item.label}>
                  {item.label}
                </option>
              );
            })}
          </select>
        </div>
        <div className="form-group col-md-12 col-12 mb-3">
          <label htmlFor="rubro">Seleccione Rubro</label>
          <div className="multiselect">
            <div className="selectBox"></div>
            <div className="checkboxes overflow-auto">
              {chkRubros.map((rubro, index) => (
                <div className="form-check" key={index}>
                  <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    className="form-check-input"
                    name={rubro.name}
                    checked={rubro?.isChecked || false}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                  />
                  <label className="form-check-label ms-2">{rubro.name}</label>
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="form-group col-12 mb-3">
          <label htmlFor="empresa">Empresa a postular</label>
          <select
            className="form-select"
            name="empresa"
            value={empresa}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
          >
            {empresas.map((item) => {
              return (
                <option name="empresa" key={item.value} value={item.label}>
                  {item.label}
                </option>
              );
            })}
          </select>
        </div>
        <div className="form-group col-12 mb-3">
          <label htmlFor="comprador">Comprador responsable</label>
          <select
            className="form-select"
            name="comprador"
            value={comprador}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
          >
            {compradores.map((item) => {
              return (
                <option name="comprador" key={item.value} value={item.label}>
                  {item.label}
                </option>
              );
            })}
          </select>
        </div>
        <div className="form-group col-12 mb-3">
          <label htmlFor="comentario">Contacto</label>
          <textarea
            className="form-control"
            name="comentario"
            disabled={disabled}
            value={comentario}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
          ></textarea>
        </div>
        <div className="d-grid gap-2">
          <button type="submit" className="btn bg-button block subtitle">
            Validar
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};


  // Utilizo un  Schema asi:
    const preRegistroSchema = Schema({

        idFiscal: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },

        pais: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },

        rubro : [{
            name : String,
            isChecked : Boolean
             }],

        empresa: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },

        comprador: {
            type: String
        },

        comentario: {
            type: String
        },
      
    });
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]